# ClickedCell DataGridView shouldn't work for column header

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and it has 4 columns. I use the event CellClick so that when user clicks on the row, then it will be removed from DataGridView. Everything works fine, but when user by mistake click on the column header(name of the column) then the CellClick event appears and of course program crashes because i'm trying to remove a row and user clicked on the column header. Can I do something with that? Is there any property to disable possibility of clicking on the column header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `CellClick` event check `e.RowIndex`, it will be -1 if clicking a column header, and you can ignore it.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0) {
            // they clicked a row..
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the e.RowIndex property.  If it's -1, this will be the header row.  See Andy G's post for a code snippet...

Are you sure you want to delete just on  a single click of the row? It seems quite dangerous to me, users could ***very*** easily click on the wrong row by mistake.  It would be better to select the row, and then either have a delete button by way of a menu strip, or by right clicking on the row and having a context menu pop up, which the user could then select a delete option.

Comment: Ahh, I made a mistake, actually it's on double click:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`-object's property **`RowIndex`**, which returns **`-1`** if a `DataGridViewRow` wasn't used in the click. I prefer to make this kind of check in one line, like this:

```
private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   // If a non-DataGridViewRow was clicked, return
   if (e.RowIndex == -1) { return; }

   // Your old code here
}
```